# Project specific socket exception: Dead network found

Tags: c#, sockets

So today I tried to create a SFtpconnection to a remote host through the [SSHNet](http://sshnet.codeplex.com) API. Tests in a quick and dirty console application worked quite fine but when referencing the the builded DLL in the project where the functionality should be added, the DLL was throwing exceptions.

Debugging the project, the exception turned out to be on the socket connect (or begin connect function):

> A socket operation encountered a dead network.

As stated before, the connection in another project to exactly the same server with the same parameters worked just fine.

I checked Project/Solution configurations. Checked the server name and other parameters carefully and made a testcase that in the specific project always fails (no matter what server) but WORKS in (new) projects:

```
var ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IPAdres),Port);
var sock = new Socket(ep.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, true);

//  Connect socket with specified timeout
var connectResult = sock.BeginConnect(ep, null, null);

if (!connectResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(180, false))
{
    throw new Exception("Timeout");
}

sock.EndConnect(connectResult);
```

But this doesn't seem like a strange example.
Does anyone has experience with this kind of error in a project specific way? Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the library was using the wrong NIC?

I encountered this exception on a Windows CE device with .net CF 2.0. In my case I was creating a socket for the GPRS interface, but the device was connected via Ethernet.